# How to style an Label in a child user control from the parent control in XAML

Tags: wpf, styles, parent-child

I have created a user control called REPORT.
I use this user control as a child of another control called MAIN.
I attach some REPORT controls to MAIN in my XAML code.
In REPORT, there are some Label.
I need to define the Content property of my Label of my REPORT in XAML.
Some REPORT's Label must contains the String X, some must contains the string Y.
It depend of the position of the REPORT object in my MAIN XAML tree.

I think style is convenient to solve this problem.
So, I write this in the MAIN XAML code:

```
        <prest:REPORT>
            <prest:REPORT.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="style_x">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="X"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="style_y">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Y"/>
                </Style>
            </prest:REPORT.Resources>
        </prest:REPORT>
```

But, I the REPORT XAML code, I cannot access to style_x and style_y.

Can you help ?
Thanks.

Comment: show me the Style code for REPORT you might need to specify it in the REPORT style.

Comment: You do not need Styles to solve this. You need a proper ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a style for prest:REPORT

Something like that :

```
<Style x:Key="ReportStyleX" TargetType="{x:Type prest:REPORT}">
  <Style.Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
          <Label Style="{StaticResource style_x}"/>
```

...